# Applying multiple filters to an array javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble applying and using two filters to an array. I have an array of files which two attributes: a filename and a file extension. Those files are displayed in a list in a view. There are two options for filtering the list -- with a simple text filter and a select dropdown based on the file extension.

Everything works fine **except the text filter does not work when the default "any" select option is chosen**. When the user chooses one of the file extensions, then the user can filter that list using the text filter.

https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-glade-hum3x?file=/App.js

Basically the filter should:

- Let the user switch between "all" and then any other extensions
- Regardless of which extension is chosen (including "all"), user can filter that list by using the text filter.

I have a feeling it's purely an issue with how the `.filter()` is applied at the bottom of the component.

I've simplified the component and removed a bunch of logic to keep it simple. Many thanks in advance.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [filenameFilterString, setfilenameFilterString] = useState("");
  const [selectedExtension, setselectedExtension] = useState("all");

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 27 || event.target.value === "") {
      event.target.value = "";
    }
    setfilenameFilterString(event.target.value);
  };

  const anArray = [
    {
      filename: "A graet first filename",
      extension: ".ppt"
    },
    {
      filename: "A second filename",
      extension: ".doc"
    },
    {
      filename: "A third filename",
      extension: ".xls"
    },
    {
      filename: "A fourth filename",
      extension: ".xls"
    }
  ];

  const getListOfUniqueExtensions = () => {
    const extensionList = anArray.map((file) => {
      return file.extension;
    });
    return [...new Set(extensionList)];
  };

  const handleFileExtensionChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setselectedExtension(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        {/* File Extensions Filter */}
        <select
          onChange={(e) => handleFileExtensionChange(e)}
          value={selectedExtension}
        >
          <option value="all">All</option>
          {getListOfUniqueExtensions().map((ext) => {
            return <option value={ext}>{ext}</option>;
          })}
        </select>

        {/* Text filter */}
        <input type="text" onKeyUp={(event) => handleKeyPress(event)}></input>

        {anArray
          .filter((file) =>
            selectedExtension === "all"
              ? file.extension.includes("")
              : file.extension.includes(selectedExtension) &&
                file.filename.toLowerCase().includes(filenameFilterString)
          )
          .map((file) => {
            return <div>{file.filename}</div>;
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Instead of a ternary operation, you could go with boolean logic: `(selectedExtension === 'all') || (file.extension.includes(selectedExtension) && file.filename.toLowerCase().includes(filenameFilterString))`

Comment: replace file.extension.includes("") by file.filename.toLowerCase().includes(filenameFilterString)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [filenameFilterString, setfilenameFilterString] = useState("");
  const [selectedExtension, setselectedExtension] = useState("all");

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    let input = event.target.value;
    setfilenameFilterString(input.toLowerCase());
  };

  const anArray = [
    {
      filename: "A graet first filename",
      extension: ".ppt"
    },
    {
      filename: "A second filename",
      extension: ".doc"
    },
    {
      filename: "A third filename",
      extension: ".xls"
    },
    {
      filename: "A fourth filename",
      extension: ".xls"
    }
  ];

  const getListOfUniqueExtensions = () => {
    const extensionList = anArray.map((file) => {
      return file.extension;
    });
    return [...new Set(extensionList)];
  };

  const handleFileExtensionChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setselectedExtension(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        {/* File Extensions Filter */}
        <select
          onChange={(e) => handleFileExtensionChange(e)}
          value={selectedExtension}
        >
          <option value="all">All</option>
          {getListOfUniqueExtensions().map((ext) => {
            return <option value={ext}>{ext}</option>;
          })}
        </select>

        {/* Text filter */}
        <input type="text" onKeyUp={(event) => handleKeyPress(event)}></input>

        {anArray
          .filter((file) =>
            selectedExtension === "all"
              ? file.filename.toLowerCase().includes(filenameFilterString)
              : file.extension.includes(selectedExtension) &&
                file.filename.toLowerCase().includes(filenameFilterString)
          )
          .map((file) => {
            return <div>{file.filename}</div>;
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Live Demo: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-pine-zj7dv?file=/src/App.js:0-1983)

Comment: This doesn't work. If you type something, then the extension flips back to All.

Comment: I think OP is trying to search the entire file list regardless of file extension when search text is provided, that's why I am resetting the extension to ```all```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is sufficient

```
        {anArray
          .filter((file) =>
            selectedExtension === "all"
              ? file.filename.toLowerCase().includes(filenameFilterString)
              : file.extension.includes(selectedExtension) &&
                file.filename.toLowerCase().includes(filenameFilterString)
          )
          .map((file) => {
            return <div>{file.filename}</div>;
          })}
```

You could also remove the duplication by using 2 chained filters:

```
        {anArray
          .filter((file) =>
            selectedExtension === "all"
              ? true
              : file.extension.includes(selectedExtension)
          )
          .filter(file => file.filename.toLowerCase().includes(filenameFilterString))
          .map((file) => {
            return <div>{file.filename}</div>;
          })}
```